# Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl not working in root site

Tags: 2013, csom, 2016

I am trying to get a file by relative url

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File home = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl.EndsWith("/") ? web.ServerRelativeUrl : web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + folderName + filename);
                ctx.Load(home);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

It throws the below exception after the last line

> Value does not fall within expected range
>   The above code works fine for all site collections except root site collection

The values of the parameters are as below

```
web.ServerRelativeUrl = "/";
folderName = "_catalogs/masterpage/";
filename = "custom.master";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had written condition statement combining with add string operation. Your statement missing wrapper and ultimately the conditional operation will return the same result for both i.e. either condition is true or false it will give same result.

Try following script:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File home = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl((web.ServerRelativeUrl.EndsWith("/") ? web.ServerRelativeUrl : web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/") + folderName + filename);
```

Comment: it happen many a times while working with conditional statements. I always wrap my conditional statements to get exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File home = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl +"/"+ folderName + "/"+filename);
```

Comment: thank you
but i guess the `/` is already there in the parameters

Comment: Did you try this? Same error?

Comment: got "File Not Found" error, the master page is there though

Comment: try ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl  instead of web.ServerRelativeUrl

Comment: Web web = ctx.Web, this is how it got declared bro

Comment: Try with my original answer. I tried your code, it gave me "File not Found". Put / and you'll get the file.